# Oracle Apex Login page (Html and CSS)

Tags: html, css, oracle-apex

I'm making a login page in Oracle APEX and I'm trying to change the icon of the login through CSS code and everything works but this little guy:

```
.t-Login-logo {
background-image:url(#APP_FILES#LogofinitoJ-removebg.jpg);
background-size:cover;
width:302px;
height:100px;
}
```

specifically ONLY the background-image line is not working, the rest does, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: my code intervention is on the inline section of the CSS page attributes in Oracle Application Express.

Comment: `#APP_FILES#LogofinitoJ-removebg.jpg` doesn't look like a valid URI. Make sure you are using the correct path to the actual image

Comment: Yes the path is correct, that's an Apex Shared Component url, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APEX doesn't resolve the substitution strings in your page "Inline CSS". You should move your CSS class to a new file, lets say `style.css`:

```css
.t-Login-logo {
  background-image:url('LogofinitoJ-removebg.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  width:302px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Then add the file reference to page section `CSS` > `File URLs` as `#APP_IMAGES#style.css`.

Comment: In the end I modified directly the html page but your solution looks like exactly what I need, I'll try it too, ty vm.